# Post-coital effects on human cognition

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, sexuality, sex-differences

I often see couples fight after sex. Why is this? Is there an actual biological effects (release of endorphins or other hormones) post-coitus (or post-orgasm) that would increase irritability in an individual?

I am trying to understand how it works and what neurons / recipes are involved in such experiences.

Comment: I think what you're asking is if there is any sort of biological process (release of endorphins or something) that would increase the aggression of both parties, thus increasing the likehood for an argument to occur?

Comment: Actually, one could indeed wonder about such things as anger, aggression, or depression. If there is postnatal depression, why wouldn't post-ejaculation depression and stuff also be considered as part of the whole picture? Thanks.

Comment: Framing the question in terms of the biological mechanisms and their potential affect on human cognition (instead of focusing on the outcome of this affect) would make this question much more answerable. Would you mind editing the question to change this focus?

Comment: I would, but I'm afraid I don't have the knowledge required to make the question more amenable. If you would kindly be able to do it for me I would love see what people think. Thanks.

Comment: I did my best! Let me know if you feel like this edit lost the spirit of the question and remember you can always roll back or modify my edits. Thank you for working with me.

Comment: "I often see couples fight after sex."  You watch couples after they've had sex?

Comment: No, I do not, and have no idea what other people's experiences are like but I assume similar. But I am unsure about anything. Could depend on many things, including, a change in something in the brain. I cannot understand it.

Comment: If you don't watch them after sex, how do you know they've just had sex (and are fighting because of it)?

Comment: Thoughts are often a combination of experience and imagination. Thanks.

Comment: It could very well be that one or both partners was hoping the sexual activity would be fulfilling and it didn't turn out as hoped. This could cause irritation in one person. The other person could sense that irritation in the other person and then an argument ensues. It could be as simple as that.

Comment: @mrt regardless of voyeurism, the question has been rephrased to be much more scientific and objective now

Comment: @Seanny123  I guess I was just trying to discern what empirical evidence (even if anecdotal) there was for post-coital fighting.  Wasn't trying to accuse him of voyeurism! ;)  We can speculate on a mechanism, but it's not clear how meaningful it would be if we don't have evidence that this actually happens.